# check if the sequence of values in subarray exist in an array using where in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Example:
if i have two array saved in database in different records
$array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
$array2 = [6,5,4,3,2,1];

and subArray
$subArray = [1,2,3];

and i want to get the array where the sequence of $subArray exists using query in laravel
which will $array1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

1. Get intersecting [keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)
2. Iterate on keys and [slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) it

```php
    function isSequence($array, $subArray){
        $keys = array_keys($array, $subArray[array_keys($subArray)[0]]); 
        foreach($keys as $key) {
            if(array_slice($array, $key, count($subArray)) == $subArray){
                return true;    
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

[SANDBOX](https://onlinephp.io/c/5a65a)

Comment: What if i want to add a condition that it is in the same key?
Example:
$array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
$array2 = [7,9,1,2,3];
and the subarray [1,2,3]
i want the answer to be only $array 1

Comment: you mean on the same indexes ?

Comment: yes same index .